# Background image change on hover of a different div

Tags: javascript, css, background

i am totally new in web design, and i am right now struggling with creating part of my website, i need to somehow make this happen:

When PART of the BODY BACKGROUND is HOVERED, make the background change to "B", and when the mouse is not over that part, I need it to change back to background "A".

**THIS is what i have so far: ( i tried using javascript, as i was told to, but it's not working for some reason!)** [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/wQdVv/)

AS of right now i have the javascript on the head of my html, like this:

```
<head>    
<script>

$('#hover').hover(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('nohover').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $('body').addClass('nohover').removeClass('hover');
});

</script>

</head>
```

**and THIS is what i wanted to show up when the COCONUT is HOVERED:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek98U.jpg

Comment: go back to your fiddle, add a 2px solid lime border to the #hover and you can see it is not the same place/location as the coconut on the page (add jQuery to it also btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Thank you, @gvee, i got it to work on my jsfiddle but it doesnt work on my website :( I added the jquery library from google, but nothing happens when i hover the coconut :(  – @rafacardosoc

I think this is probably because jsFiddle adds a little extra code for you that you're not realising.

Here's a complete html script for you to use. Pay particular attention do the bit starting with `$(document).ready(...`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coconut').hover(function() {
            $('body').addClass('hover');
        }, function(){
            $('body').removeClass('hover');
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body
      {
        background-image: url('http://s5.postimg.org/6qbplw2xj/Background_main.jpg');
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: black;
        height: 800px;
        width: 800px;
      }

      #coconut
      {
        position: absolute;
        width: 450px;
        height: 400px;
        top: 300px;
        right: 20px;
        border: 2px solid red;
      }

      .hover
      {
        background-image: url('http://s5.postimg.org/8jj7nydhz/Background_main.jpg');
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>

  <div id="coconut"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YAAAY! got it to work on my websiiiiite! THAK YO SO VERY MUCH @gvee!
NOW i just have to find out WHY it went crazy when i launched it!
any ideas? www.tasteofbrazilkc.com

Answer (score 2):

Your `#hover` element needs to have a background-color or image or something that allows it to be hoverable.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wQdVv/3/)

```css
#hover {
    /* your styles ... */
    background-color:#fff; /* or something */
}
```

Also, yes, be sure that you've selected jQuery in the **Frameworks & Extensions** sidebar.

Comment: what you did on your JSFIDDLE didnt work, at least to me, nothing happens when i hover over the coconut :(

Comment: You don't hover over the coconut. You hover over that white box in the corner. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated based on OP comments**

In your jsFiddle you need to pick the JQuery library. Your code works just fine.

On the **Frameworks & Extensions** chose one of the JQuery libraries from the top dropown box.

To extend my answer, I think your code is more complicated than it needs to be. Here's a revised (and simplified) version:

### HTML

```
<div id="coconut"></div>
```

### CSS

```css
body {
    background-image:url('http://s5.postimg.org/6qbplw2xj/Background_main.jpg');
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:black;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
}

#coconut {
    position:absolute;
    width:450px;
    height:400px;
    top:300px;
    right:20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.hover {
    background-image:url('http://s5.postimg.org/8jj7nydhz/Background_main.jpg');
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('#coconut').hover(function() {
    $('body').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $('body').removeClass('hover');
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wQdVv/7/

Comment: Thanks @AlexMorrise , that did confuse me too as it was a correct and complete answer... right? I am new to SO so if there's some netiquette I've missed can someone please let me know? I have since expanded and provided an alternative solution too.

Comment: @gvee: i dont want it to change to the other background if you hover ANY part of the backgroun, BUT ONLY when you hover the COCONUT...

Comment: Thank you, @gvee, i got it to work on my jsfiddle but it doesnt work on my website :(
I added the jquery library from google, but nothing happens when i hover the coconut :(

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Comment: Updated my post based on your comments. Now requires JQuery.

Comment: @rafacardosoc can you post a link to your website?

Comment: @gvee: i didn't have my website posted anywhere, since i was still workin on it, i have no launched it but it went crazy, nothing shows up but the footer! any ideas? ( you can still see my source code though!)
www.tasteofbrazilkc.com

Comment: @rafacardosoc I have posted another full response to your question... take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` pseudoclass instead of jQuery.

```css
#hover:hover {
/* your code */
}
```

And also, for transparent images you should use `.png`, not `.jpg`.